# how to put image and text on same line

Tags: images

trying to image and text on same line but images always stand up little bit above after posting my article.But while my post in draft is,the image is not rebellious What could i do to arrange images and textes in order?

before posting:

[image]

after posting:

[image]

Comment: `text <span style="vertical-align: middle;"><img src="path/to/image.ext" alt="img"></span> ends here`. You can try the other properties of `vertical-align`. But the question is not specific to WordPress, hence off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to differing `line-heights` and `font-size`s between the editor, and the live site.  You can try setting the `vertical-align` on the image (middle), or css `position: relative`, and setting bottom or top plus or minus a number of pixels.  If you do this often, it would be easiest to define a css class and assigning the class to the images.

```
<img class="inline-image" src="...">

<style>
.inline-image {
   position: relative;
   top: -3px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: so styling images on the same page or with external(by calling) a CSS file which is better?

Comment: most people prefer using an external css file.  This way the styling rules are all contained in a single location, and the browser can cache it separately.

Comment: To futher clarify, placing it in an external file means you can reuse it on any post/page.  If it were contained within the post/page, it would not be reusable.

Comment: if i need it for just single page?